# Development --> Production server(scripts for change in table structure)

Tags: sql-server

Whenever i move the changes from  development to production server.
I Drop scripts for stored procedures, functions.
Then generate new scripts for stored procedures, functions.
But for new tables creation, i only create scripts. 
But for change in the table structure, i make a note of change in the fields(if they are less), OR create a alter script and keep everything ready.

Whenever i move from development to prodction, on one go i execute all the scripts.

But this time, i have not created the scripts for change in table structure. It is a tedious job, to make a track of change in the structures for all the tables. Make these changes in production.

Any suggestions or new procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) to generate your scripts. It's not free but pays for itself in saved time easily.

If you can't justify the cost (maybe this is just an occasional need?) A free way of just reminding yourself of what changed might be to script out both database definitions then do a compare in [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) to see the differences.